# How to intercept all touch events?

Tags: android

How can I get an "top" `View` of my application (which contains `Activity` and all `DialogFragment`s)? I need to intercept all touch events to handle motion of some `View` between `DialogFragment` and my `Activity`.

I've tried to catch them (event) through the decor view of Activity's `Window` with no luck:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setOnTouchListener(...);
```

Comment: Overriding the Activity#dispatchTouchEvent(..) method allows you to intercept all touch events prior to the View:s seeing them.

Comment: @Jens it's true, but it doesn't intercept touches on `DialogFragment` (because it belongs to another window maybe)

Comment: I guess you've tried putting your own TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT window atop of everything using WindowManager#addView(..)?

Comment: It will probably clobber your dialog fragments however (i.e. hide them).

Comment: as I can tell from my experience, an idea with adding a `View` using `WindowManager` didn't go well. 
I've tried it as a transparent view that was overlayed above the app. It consumed all click events and did not pass them further to my app's window.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can override the [`Activity.dispatchTouchEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) to intercept all touch events in your activity, even if you have some Views like ScrollView, Button, etc that will consume the touch event.

Combining with[`ViewGroup.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean)), you can disable the touch event of the ViewGroup. For example, if you want to disable all the touch event in some ViewGroup, try this:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.topLevelRelativeLayout),
            true
    );
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}

private void requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(ViewGroup v, boolean disallowIntercept) {
    v.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept);
    int childCount = v.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View child = v.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent((ViewGroup) child, disallowIntercept);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there possibility to do it without overriding method ?

Answer (score 0):

If you wonder how to intercept all touch events in `DialogFragments`, here you go:

```
abstract class BaseDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return object : Dialog(requireContext()){
            override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                // do your thing here
                return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
            }
        }
    }

}
```